# jquery - Paypal (Adaptive Payment API Integration By AJAX)

Tags: jquery, paypal, jquery-mobile

I have some doubts in the paypal integration in my website.

Actually I have been worked on the jquery and jquerymobile frameworks. I want to integrate the paypal API in my site. I want to use the AdaptivePayment API(Paypal) in my site.

How to do it ? Please share your views.

Is it possible to do from the jquery?

I had seen a lot of samples in the java ,Asp.net and PHP. But I could not see a single sample developed by jquery(AJAX).

Have ever you see the samples regarding this? Please friends share your views and give the guidance to me.

THanks..

I wrote a sample for calling the paypal adaptive payment API. But I could not get the success state. I had got the error status as 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an [implementation in Python](https://github.com/adeel/paypal/blob/master/payment.py) which you can use as a starting point.  Really all you need to do is send a POST request with jQuery to the API url.

Comment: Thanks adeel. Could please make it clear little bit more? unless I haven't use any serverside(java,php and python) code, I could not integrate the adaptivePayment API. Am I right ? Without server side coding ,I never integrate the API through jquery only like only js and HTML. is it correct? I think , It will give the cross domain issues.

Comment: Which operation do you want to use exactly?  Just `Pay` (https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-1414)?